# Use Quasar, On mouse event, display a list

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am doing web development through quasar framework. I want to create a mouse event. I want the following menu to be displayed when a mouse over event, not a mouse click event. I made this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jd-0001/pen/GRRVxLZ?editors=1010) as a reference, but my code didn't work on my web. Help. Excerpts from some of my code. What I want to know is 'how the mouseover event works' in vue3.0?

This is my Code

```html
<!-- html -->
<template>
  <q-btn
    label="MyBtnName"
    @mouseover="menuOver = true"
    @mouseleave="menuOver = false"
  >
    <q-menu v-model="menuOpen">
      <q-list>
        <q-item
          @mouseover="listOver = true"
          @mouseleave="listOver = false"
           >
          <q-item-section>
            {{ MyItems }}
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-menu>
  </q-btn>
</template>
```

```js
// script
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { debounce } from 'quasar';

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      menuOpen: ref(false),
      menuOver: ref(false),
      listOver: ref(false),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    debounceFunc() {
      debounce(() => {
        this.checkMenu();
      }, 100);
    },
    checkMenu() {
      if (this.menuOver || this.listOver) {
        this.menuOpen = true;
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    mouseOver() {
      return this.debounceFunc();
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is, that you try to add events to anb element which don´t accept these events. According to the documentation of `quasar` at [Button | QBtn API](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button#qbtn-api), you can only use the `click`-event.

Why did it work in your codepen? Different to `q-btn` the `div` you used in codepen is already as it would be displayed. `q-btn` will be rendered, so everything not considered, like `@mouseover="menuOver = true"`, will be lost.

Simple solution? Just build your own kind of button as a `div` or a `button` element, like you already done in your codepen.

Comment: I just made it with a tag by adding the 'type' attribute. Still not working though.

Comment: @eeezkim You did what? Can you please edit your question so I can see what you tried?